# Selection Sorting

Tags: python, selection-sort

I have this code that takes a txt file that prints out a list of countries.

```
def readCountries(filename):
    result=[]
    lines=open(filename)

    for line in lines:
        result.append(line.strip('\n').split(',\t'))
    for sublist in result:
        sublist[1]=float(sublist[1])
        sublist[2]=int(sublist[2])

    return result
```

I am trying to create a selection sort that sorts the list by population in descending order, and will print the information.

Here is my code what am I doing wrong?

```
def countryByPop(population):
    myList=readCountries('countries.txt')

    for i in range(0,len(myList)):
        largest = i
        for j in range(i,len(myList)):
            if myList[j]<myList[smallest]:
                smallest = j
        temp = myList[i]
        myList[i] = myList[smallest]
        myList[smallest] = temp

    if population range(0,len(myList))
        return temp
    else:
        print "Invalid Parameter: %s" %(population)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you define the variable `largest` and never use it again. You then use the undefined variable `smallest`. I assume you meant to change all instances of `smallest` to `largest` and the `largest` is to be the index in the list that points to the country with the largest population. You should change all instances of `smallest` to `largest`.

To sort in descending order you want to find the largest item on each iteration of the outer for loop and then move it to `myList[i]`. However, by testing `myList[j] < myList[smallest]` you end up moving the smallest element to the beginning of the list. You should change that to `>` instead of `<`. This way the inner for loop will find the country that has a larger population than the one pointed to by `largest`.

Also, your if statement is not actually checking the country population. Each element of myList is a list. So you are comparing a list to a list. Instead you want to compare an element of the list. If the third element of your list stores the population then the statement should read `myList[j][2] > myList[largest][2]`. Notice the second set of braces to access that population element.

```
def countryByPop(population):
    myList=readCountries('countries.txt')

    for i in range(0,len(myList)):
        largest = i
        for j in range(i, len(myList)):
            if myList[j][2] > myList[largest][2]:
                largest = j
        temp = myList[i]
        myList[i] = myList[largest]
        myList[largest] = temp

    if population < len(myList):
        return myList[population-1]
    else:
        print "Invalid Parameter: %s" % (population)
```

If the `population` parameter is meant to retrieve the nth most populous country then you retrieve that item by `myList[population-1]`. The use of `range()` in the if statement was unnecessary. The code reflects this change. You should use a better name than `population` to clarify the intent, such as `country_rank`.

Comment: Thanks! How would I output the place in the list where the parameter  I entered is?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean? You want the index of the country whose population matches the population that you pass in?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure how to output it. Say when I enter in countryByPop(18), I want the 18th most populated country to be printed, which would be the 18th value in the list

Comment: Understood. You can reference it by `myList[population-1]`. You must subtract 1 because lists are 0 based.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning `mylist`

```
def countryByPop(population):
    ...
    return mylist
```

You also need to be clear about what the variables `smallest` and `largest` mean. I don't see where `smallest` is assigned before it is used.

Assuming the name of the country is the first element in the records, you need to be comparing `myList[j][1] < myList[smallest][1]` for example if the population is the second element

finally, in Python, you can write these three lines

```
    temp = myList[i]
    myList[i] = myList[smallest]
    myList[smallest] = temp
```

as one

```
    myList[i], myList[smallest] = myList[smallest], myList[i]
```

Comment: Would I write return myList in the if statement? Or keep the return temp?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in jquery,it's very simple.

var Selectionsort = function (A) {

```
        for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            var imin = i;
                for (var j = i + 1; j <= A.length; j++) {
                    if (A[j] < A[imin]) 
                        imin = j;
                }
                var tmp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[imin];
                A[imin] = tmp;
        }
        return A;
    };
    var A = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80];
    var Aftersorted = Selectionsort(A);
    console.log(Aftersorted);
```